# Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.8

Tags: scala, sbt

i have fresh ubuntu 15.04 and i installed sbt by [this](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html) guide with

```
echo "deb http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbt
```

then i just run command in terminal

```
sbt
```

output saying that sbt is trying to install (many many [SUCCESS] messages) and after all there are some error messages like

```
:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.json4s#json4s-core_2.10;3.2.10: not found
unresolved dependency: org.spire-math#jawn-parser_2.10;0.6.0: not found
unresolved dependency: org.spire-math#json4s-support_2.10;0.6.0: not found
download failed: org.scalamacros#quasiquotes_2.10;2.0.1!quasiquotes_2.10.jar
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
(see /home/dima/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.8
```

[here](https://gist.github.com/melodicwing/1ab49b70dd36292ec4d0) is a full log from /home/dima/.sbt/boot/update.log

help please what should i do to fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of errors like these in the logs:

```
SERVER ERROR: Connection timed out url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalamacros/quasiquotes_2.10/2.0.1/quasiquotes_2.10-2.0.1.pom.sha1
```

These suggest there was a (perhaps) temporary network issue. If you try the URL with get or curl do you see a similar error?